# Override equals to check against class type or primitive int

Tags: java, overriding, equals

I'm trying to figure out a way to have my class' equals method work for either the class type or a primitive int but something doesn't feel right about the approach I have:

```
class MyClass {
    int myID;
    ....
    [other class variables/methods]
    ....

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof MyClass)) {
            // False if neither an int nor a myClass
            if (!(obj.getClass().equals(int.class))) {
                return false
            }
            // If int, check against myID
            return ((int) obj).myID == myID);
        }
        // If myClass check against that object's myID
        return ((MyClass) obj).myID == myID);
    }
}
```

The reason I'd like to do this is if I have an ArrayList myClassList I want to be able to do .contains for either an instance of MyClass or an int, without having to manually iterate the ArrayList for an int. So like this:

```
ArrayList<MyClass> myClassList = new ArrayList<MyClass>();

int someID = 5;
MyClass myClass = new MyClass([initialize with myID = 5]);
MyClass otherClass = new MyClass(myClass);

myClassList.add(myClass);

myClassList.contains(otherClass); // returns true
myClassList.contains(someID); // returns true
```

I've never come across this before, so I don't know what the cleanest approach is.

Comment: An `ArrayList` can't contain primitive `int`(s).

Comment: This is a bad idea. Use the appropriate technique, iterate. Or use a map.

Comment: Creating a pojo which can be equal to an `int` sounds like a bad idea and will/can result in confusing code and behavior. It might be "cool" to use `myClassList.contains(someID);`, but another approach, like iterating manually, will result in much cleaner and more unstandable code.

Comment: I can't check right now, but I'm fairly sure that when you do `ArrayList.contains(b)` it's actually `b.equals(...)` that gets called, rather than `.equals(b)`. Since you can't override `equals` of the `Integer` class, this can't be made to work.

Comment: @PaulBoddington It does `o.equals(e)`. `o` being argument, `e` being element in list.

Comment: @Pillar Thanks. That makes more sense as you only have to check for `null` once. Not that it matters - this would be a terrible idea even if it worked!

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I know an ArrayList can't contain an int, but wasn't aware that it's equals method wouldn't allow to check against an int contained within the ArrayList's type.

Comment: @Pillar I wasn't comfortable with it to begin with honestly, just curious since I've never thought about this before. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are storing up trouble for yourself by breaking the contract of the `equals` method, even if you can figure out a way to make it work.

How about Java 8 streams?

```
static boolean listContainsId(List<MyClass> list, int id) {
    return list.stream().anyMatch(mc -> mc.myID == id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about create your own ArrayList type.

```
public class MyArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {

    public boolean contains(int id) {
        return super.contains(new MyClass(id));
    }
}
```